# Jquery - Run css rules on 3 divs in a loop one Each every N seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have 3 HTML divs for example:

**HTML**

```
<div id="one" class="hide">Text one</div>
<div id="two" >Text two</div>
<div id="three" class="hide">Text three</div>
```

I want Jquery to change every N seconds the css like this:

**JS**

```
// First N seconds : 
$("#two").hide(); 
$("#one").show();

//Next N seconds:
$("#one").hide(); 
$("#three").show();

//Next N seconds:
$("#three").hide(); 
$("#two").show();
```

Next N seconds: Do again the "First N seconds" action, and after loop again the next two.

I've tried with set Interval, But not sure how to achieve this to work, Because its goes over one action or a few each time.

I thought about checking if divs are visible by css, and by that do the actions, But i'm looking for a way to perform this without counting on CSS of divs for doing actions each N seconds.

The divs could be anywhere in the page, so cant use "next" to reach the next div, i will need to run over them from a array with the divs ID's. For example:

```
idArray=["one", "two", "three"];
```

Comment: First off, you are using a `class selector`, but the same divs have id's instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is a bit misleading as the selectors you have mentioned have the id's instead of classes that is intended.

You can instead access all the divs and using a combination of `setInterval` , `addClass` , `removeClass` and `hide` methods whip something out.

```
var $curr =  $('div').first();
// Hide all the divs
$('div').addClass('hide');
// Display the first div
$curr.removeClass('hide'); 

var interval = setInterval(function() {
    // Hide all the divs
    $('div').addClass('hide');
    if($curr) {
        $curr = $curr.next('div');
    }

    if($curr && $curr.length === 0) {
         $curr = $('div').first();   
    }
    $curr.removeClass('hide');                       
}, 500);
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/3bct8r9a/)**

**UPDATE**

Elements that are present anywhere on the page. For this to work, I would have a common class on all the elements that have to be shown and hidden.

```
var $curr = $('.toggle').first();
// Hide all the divs
$('.toggle').addClass('hide');
// Display the first div
$curr.removeClass('hide');

var interval = setInterval(function () {
    // Hide all the divs
    $('.toggle').addClass('hide');
    var len = $('.toggle').length,
        found = false;

    $(".toggle").each(function(index) {
        // If the curr element is the 
        // element in iteration
        // select the next indexed element..
        if($(this).is($curr) && !found) {
             var nextIndex = index + 1;
            if(nextIndex >= len) {
                $curr = $('.toggle').first();
            } else {
                $curr = $('.toggle').eq(nextIndex);
                found = true;
            }
         }
    });
    $curr.removeClass('hide');
}, 500);
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/3bct8r9a/3/)**

Comment: The example works perfect. The problem is that the divs could be anywhere in page, so "next" will work in this case.  Added that to the question now, sorry  about not mention it before.

Comment: @batz If that is the case I have updated the code. Check the post which should work no matter where the element is provided it is given a common class.

Comment: Glad to have helped :)